# AWS CLI "s3 ls" command to list a date range of files in a virtual folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm trying to list files from a virtual folder in S3 within a specific date range. For example: all the files that have been uploaded for the month of February.

I currently run a `aws s3 ls` command but that gives all the files:

```
aws s3 ls s3://Bucket/VirtualFolder/VirtualFolder --recursive --human-readable --summarize > c:File.txt
```

How can I get it to list only the files within a given date range?

Comment: Not possible. `s3 ls` command does not support what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, so my next question is their a way?

Answer (score 11):

You could filter the results with a tool like awk:

```
aws s3 ls s3://Bucket/VirtualFolder/VirtualFolder --recursive --human-readable --summarize \
| awk -F'[-: ]' '$1 >= 2016 && $2 >= 3 { print }'
```

Where awk splits each records using -, :, and space delimiters so you can address fields as:

- $1 - year
- $2 - month
- $3 - day
- $4 - hour
- $5 - minute
- $6 - second

Comment: This is useful. :)

Comment: Note for windows users: You have to change quoting, so `'` to `"`

Answer (score 4):

The aws cli ls command does not support filters, so you will have to bring back all of the results and filter locally.

Comment: Some years later here... Is it still the case that `aws cli s3 ls` does not support date filter parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Realizing this question was tagged `command-line-interface`, I have found the best way to address non-trivial aws-cli desires is to write a Python script.

Tersest example:

`$ python3 -c "import boto3; print(boto3.client('s3').list_buckets()['Buckets'][0])"`

Returns: (for me)

`{'Name': 'aws-glue-scripts-282302944235-us-west-1', 'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 22, 0, 40, 5, tzinfo=tzutc())}`

That one-liner isn't a profound script, but it can be expounded into one. (Probably with less effort than munging a `bash` script, much as I love `bash`.) After looking up a few `boto3` calls, you can deduce the rest from equivalent cli commands.